# If i download the 160GB downloading , i will be global node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

i have a question , i've searched a lot but no answers i get
i've installed bitcoin core and after opening the app , it is downloading about 160GB and its gonna take two weeks to be completed
my question is , if i wait this time and the download be completed , am i supposed to be a global node?
my wallet will be saved in global servers?
beacuse now in local version , my wallet will be removed each time i restart the server or backuping the regtest wallet with fake balance , will import me an empty wallet!
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Running a mainnet full node uses up closer to 300 GB as of the time of this answer, not 160 GB.

Once your node is synced, any transactions you make will be part of the bitcoin mainnet, and thus persistent. However, you are still responsible for backing up and maintaining access to your private keys - if you delete or otherwise reset the wallet, you will still lose access to your coins - except, on the mainnet, those coins are worth considerable amounts of money.

The regtest is meant to be a local network for testing various failure modes which are not easy to replicate on the mainnet or testnets frequently. It is not intended to be run as a permanent network.

For testing, you should consider running a testnet node, which has all the benefits of the mainnet, without requiring you to spend actual money and BTC - you will still need to be responsible for your keys, but your transactions will be persistent.